# Почему на разных телефонах некорректно отображается шрифт

Tags: java, android, шрифты, ui

***На картинках обведено квадратами по центру экрана***

**На 1 картинке не отображается телефон Xiaomi Redmi 4a**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**На 2 картинке все хорошо телефон Xiaomi Redmi Note 5**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**На 3 картинке тоже все хорошо Honor 9 lite**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/cmTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital7momo"
    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Версии ОС**

1. Xiaomi Redmi 4a - Android 7.1 ,MIUI 10.2
2. Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 - Android 8.1, MIUI 10.2
3. Honor 9 Lite - Android 8.0, EMUI LLD-L31 8.0.0.144(C10)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На глаз видно что на картинке снизу размер шрифта больше, он не помещается поэтому "проседает вниз".

Comment: @Style-7 Дело не в том, а в том что шрифт на 1 картинке не совпадает с другими

Comment: а я и не говорю, что он не совпадает, я сравниваю нижнюю и среднюю картинку, размер разный (попытка № 2)

Comment: а каким образом вы подгружаете свой шрифт?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev в xml файле через android:fontFamily

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку и укажите версии ОС на телефонах. Ну и пояснить где именно проблема на картинке не помешает - я 2 минуты картинки рассматривал пока понял где проблема)

Comment: @ЮрийСпб обновил вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте `app:fontFamily` вместо `android:fontFamily`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал на honor 9 Lite (на нем все работало), поставил app:fontFamaly перестало работать

Comment: Попробуйте решение из конца ответа тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052924/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб решил вопрос, спасибо за участие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал изменение шрифта программно, все работает

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), R.font.digital7momo);
cmTimer.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Тоже замечал такое, что, android:fontFamily="@font/digital7momo" не всегда срабатывает. А почему?

Comment: @DuosDuo сам не знаю почему так